# Python: drop value=0 row in specific columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to drop rows with zero value in specific columns

```
>>> df

   salary   age   gender
0   10000    23     1
1   15000    34     0
2   23000    21     1
3     0      20     0
4   28500     0     1
5   35000    37     1
```

some data in columns salary and age are missing
and the third column, gender is a binary variables, which 1 means male 0 means female. And 0 here is not a missing data,
I want to drop the row in either salary or age is missing
so I can get

```
>>> df
   salary   age   gender
0   10000    23     1
1   15000    34     0
2   23000    21     1
3   35000    37     1
```

Comment: `df = df[(df['salary'] > 0) & (df['age'] > 0)]`

Comment: thanks you for editing the format for me

Comment: this is my first time asking a question on this forum 
after I posted this question I found the format is terrible
And you edited it before I did
Thanks alot

Comment: df = df[(df['Patient_Sub_Market'] != '0') & (df['Patient_Zip_and_City'] != '0')]

I got rid of the rows that had zeros using the above statement.

Answer (score 15):

**Option 1**

You can filter your dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.loc`:

```
df = df.loc[~((df['salary'] == 0) | (df['age'] == 0))]
```

**Option 2**

Or a smarter way to implement your logic:

```
df = df.loc[df['salary'] * df['age'] != 0]
```

This works because if either salary or age are 0, their product will also be 0.

**Option 3**

The following method can be easily extended to several columns:

```
df.loc[(df[['a', 'b']] != 0).all(axis=1)]
```

**Explanation**

- In all 3 cases, Boolean arrays are generated which are used to index your dataframe.
- All these methods can be further optimised by using `numpy` representation, e.g. `df['salary'].values`.